# How to generate a report in a pdf or word format on a webpage?

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I have a `html/php` code as shown below which on click of a download button at `Line Z` executes a php file. The drop-down list which I have from the select element at Line A is:

1. Hi
2. Hello
3. Good Morning
4. Good Evening

Let us suppose, I have selected `Hi` from the dropdown list above. On hitting download button at Line Z, `php file (hi.php)` belonging to `Hi` dropdown gets executed.

```
<form method="get" action="fr_get.php">
    <h1>Report</h1>
    <select name="report"> <!-- Line A -->
        <?php
        foreach ($reports->getReports() as $report) {
            $users = $report->getAll('AllowedUser'); ?>

            <option value="<?= $report->path; ?>"><?= (is_array($users) && in_array('deleted',
                    $users) ? 'DELETED --- ' : '').$report->getFirst('Title'); ?></option>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Download"/></div>   <!-- Line Z -->
</form>
```

The code inside `fr_get.php` is

```
<?php

$db = connect_mysql();

if (!is_admin()) {
    die('Access Denied.');
}

$report = $_GET['report'];

include($report);
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the `php code` above in the file `fr_get.php` so that on click of Download button at `Line Z`, `report in the format of pdf or word gets downloaded`.

Comment: Find a PHP library that can generate PDF or Word and learn how to use it (or read the specification for PDF or Word and do it the hard way).

Comment: What should be the content of the pdf?

Comment: It is not clear if you want hints on libraries to make pdf and word and how to use them, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you control what is in the drop-down list and therefore there must be a well-know list of possibilities. For each possible document you can create a Word file manually and save it in Word or PDF forma to the correct directory (the full path to this file is defined by `$report->path` just like you already are doing it). In the following code I am assuming you have chosen PDF format:

```
<?php

$db = connect_mysql();

if (!is_admin()) {
    die('Access Denied.');
}


if (!isset($_GET['report'])) {
    # Some action if a report parameter is missing, for example:
    throw new Exception('Invalid request.');
}

$report = $_GET['report'];

if (!file_exists($report)) {
    # Some action if a bad path is passed, for example:
    throw new Exception("Bad report name: $report");
}

$attachmentName = basename($report);

header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$attachmentName");
file_get_contents($report);
```